# Flash CS4 - Component Inspector, properties always null?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've created a small component in Flash CS4, and I have associated my MyComp symbol with it's respective MyComp class. The code in MyComp.as looks as follows:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class MyComp extends MovieClip
    {
        public function MyComp()
        {
            trace(this.test);
        }

        private var _test:String;

        [Inspectable(defaultValue="blah")]
        public function get test():String
        {
            return this._test;
        }

        public function set test(v:String):void
        {
            this._test = v;
        }
    }
}
```

When I drag the component to a test FLA, the component's properties are all showing up as per the Inspectable[] meta tag. But when I set the properties in the Component Inspector, the value is always null, despite what the Component Inspector says.

When tracing for example test, it always outputs null?

How do I get the Component Inspector's values to reflect in the component at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of operations with components and inspectable properties can be a bit tricky. Keith Peters (Bit-101) wrote up [a nice overview of the problems with inspectable getters and setters](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=511).

The issue, in particular, is that the constructor gets called PRIOR to the inspectable properties being set. One nice way around this is to make your constructor setup a listener for the EXIT_FRAME event, which will run during the same frame, just after everything else is done. For example:

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class SampleComponent extends MovieClip {

        private var _foo:Number;

        public function SampleComponent() {
            trace("SampleComponent: constructor");
            addEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME, onReady);
        }

        [Inspectable]
        public function get foo():Number {
            trace("SampleComponent: get foo: " + _foo);
            return _foo;
        }

        public function set foo(value:Number):void {
            trace("SampleComponent: set foo: " + value);
            _foo = value;
        }

        private function onReady(event:Event):void {
            trace("SampleComponent: ready!");
            removeEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME, onReady);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link Branden! I've been pulling my hair out of my scalp for two weeks now, and can't get things working. I'll let know shortly if I managed to come across a solution.

Comment: After reading the above link, I noticed my problem is due to me tracing in the constructor, before the component has finished initializing. I'll retry with an ADDED_TO_STAGE event or something likewise. Thanks for the post!

Comment: Mmm. On ADDED_TO_STAGE, still null, thus still too early. Does Flash fire an event when the component has been created/initialized?

Comment: Well, because this is a display object you can tap into the ENTER_FRAME event, but that would be fired a frame too late, so instead, try the new (to Flash 9) Event.EXIT_FRAME event. I'll post a code example in my answer in just a second.

Comment: I hate Flash Professional, yet I love ActionScript 3. :)

Comment: It looks Event.EXIT_FRAME is Flash 10 only since I get undefined props error when it does compiled for Flash 9, contrary to the Doc....

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the text string "exitFrame", like this:

```
addEventListener( "exitFrame", onExitFrame );
```

The event fires, it seems the Event class is just missing the definition.